# ffmpeg is not capturing udp output

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, udp

I'm trying to capture UDP output with ffmpeg, but the stream looks empty. Just for background, the output is produced by GoPro camera and I'm connecting to its Wifi. I can see with wireshark a lot of udp packets sent to my ip from GoPro IP, but nothing appears in ffmpeg.

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -f:v mpegts -probesize 8192 udp://10.5.5.9:8554
ffplay version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Any idea or suggestion how could I debug or understand the cause?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `ffmpeg -f mpegts udp://10.5.5.9:8554`?

Comment: @gyan     Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://10.5.5.9:8554':
    Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Comment: Sorry, what's the output of `ffmpeg -f mpegts -i udp://10.5.5.9:8554`?

Comment: Yes. So I assume, that ffmpeg doesn't recognize the stream, which I can observe with Wireshark, right?

Comment: @gyan  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100 and then nothing changes.

Comment: Paste the full log into the question.